# How can I change Simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an application where I strongly prefer $1+\frac{3}{2+3x}$ over $\frac{5+3x}{2+3x}$, and $\sin(2x)$ over $2\sin(x)\cos(x)$. In general, I prefer to minimize the number of occurrences of the variables.

Is there a way to set the "cost" function for Simplify to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the example in OP `FullSimplify` gives the desired result:

```
FullSimplify [(5 + 3 x)/(2 + 3 x)]
```

> 1 + 3/(2 + 3 x)

To take a different example for which neither `Simplify` nor `FullSimplify` makes the desired simplification without additional work:

```
expr = (5 + 2 x)/(2 + 3 x);

Simplify  @ expr
```

> (5 + 2 x)/(2 + 3 x)

```
FullSimplify @ expr
```

> (5 + 2 x)/(2 + 3 x)

*"to minimize the number of occurrences of the variables"*  you can use a custom [`ComplexityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) that penalizes multiple occurences of symbols. For example,

```
cF = Simplify`SimplifyCount[#] + 100 Count[#, _Symbol, All] &;
```

Using it with `FullSimplify`

```
FullSimplify[expr, ComplexityFunction -> cF]
```

> 2/3 + 11/(6 + 9 x)

With `Simplify` we need to do more:

```
Simplify[expr, ComplexityFunction -> cF]
```

> (5 + 2 x)/(2 + 3 x)

Adding `Apart` to the `Automatic` [`TransformationFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunctions.html) used by `Simplify` gives the desired result:

```
Simplify[expr, ComplexityFunction -> cF, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, Apart}]
```

> 2/3 + 11/(6 + 9 x)

Comment: Isn't simple `Apart` enough? It gives 2/3 + 11/(3 (2+3 x)). One can then also expand denominator with `ExpandAll` to get 2/3 + 11/(6+9 x).

Comment: My actual target functions may have 100s of terms involving some trigonometry, some logarithms, and many rational functions. I wasn't aware of ComplexityFunction, and that's what was missing.